# how to view complete excel page with formatting while importing data from MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a form that looks like a Microsoft Excel sheet. User is entering data in form and submitting it. The data is successfully getting inserted into my database MySql. 
I want to retrieve data from MySql and show echo the database values on my page in a excel sheet grid view.

Comment: Did u try anything...

Comment: Read the data from the database and echo to appropriate cells in an HTML table

Comment: @Mark: I am a newbie to PHP. I dont know how to do it. Can u help me with the code.

Comment: Not really anything to do with excel? Or am I confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

- First is to use html tables when fetching data.
- Second is just make a simple input boxes & when you click submit, it will save as an excel file, in a temporary folder, php will fetch it and sql will save it in the database. Then you can just have a simple upload function to upload the excel file to your browser and it will display in a proper grid view. I have made this before and I can assure you this is possible. But if your still learning php, the first option is the fastest and easiest way.

Comment: Thank you. Can you share the code of your mentioned first option. Please

Comment: Hmm, just echo each data from the database in a html table :D
I think it goes like this echo'<tr><td>$row[id]</tr></td>'; something like this, this will depend on your sql query though, make sure your query is working fine so there would be no any problem in printing data.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sno] => 1
            [date] => 2015-07-11
            [project_name] => CalmClearMind
            [task_description] => dfgfhfghgf
            [time_taken] => gfjghjghjkghjghj
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sno] => 5
            [date] => 2015-07-11
            [project_name] => HRDSq
            [task_description] => dfgfhfghgf
            [time_taken] => fghf
        )

)

I am getting from database. Now how to put these into a table format??